# Custom styled combobox in own namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a bunch of user controls in an own namespace:

```
<ui:CustomTextboxWithDescription
        Description="TestProperty2"
        Text="{Binding TestProperty2}" />

<ui:CustomCheckBoxWithDescription
        Description="test"
        Value="{Binding BooleanTestProperty}" />
```

I have created a style for a combobox in an resource dictionary and used it like this:

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource StyleComboBox}">
    <ComboBoxItem>test1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>test2</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Now I want this combobox with its implizit style to appear in the "ui"-namespace like this:

```
<ui:ComboBox>
    <ComboBoxItem>test1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>test2</ComboBoxItem>
</ui:ComboBox>
```

Is there an easy way to do this, without wrapping it in an user-control?

Comment: Where did you declare the style? Is it inside App.xaml?

Comment: no, it has its own resource dictionary

Comment: in this case, it is easier for human to comprehend what `<ui:ComboBox>` is (so the word _implicitly_), but the compiler needs to be told explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an easy way to do this, without wrapping it in an user-control?

If I understand you correctly you could just create a namespace mapping:

```
<ResourceDictionary ... xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=PresentationFramework">

<ui:ComboBox>...</ui:ComboBox>
```

Comment: what you do is a mapping for all controls, but i just want the combobox....

Comment: What difference does it make? You don't have to write ui: in front of the other controls.

Comment: I'm working on a plugin framework. The other plugin programmers should just use my controls from the "ui" namespace, so there shouldn't be all wpf controls

Comment: So why would you want to put the built-in ComboBox into your custom namespace? This makes no sense at all. Anyway, you *cannot* map only a single control in a CLR namespace to a XAML namespace so this is not possible.

Comment: ok, i'll try to explain: i'm building controls which other programmers should use. by now i have only user-controls mapped to the "ui" namespace. So the programmers type in <ui:....> and intelisense show them, which controls they are allowed to use. now i want to add the comboxbox, because they are allowed to use that combobox...

Comment: Is "the ComboBox" your own custom ComboBox control then? You cannot stop someone from using the built-in one without typing ui:.

Comment: no it's just the build in combobox with a style... yes i know i cannot stop someone, but i can write a programming guideline which says that... i'm also open for other solutions....

Comment: Create a custom ComboBox control with your custom Style applied to it by default.